# Main matrix job sometimes blocks its subjobs

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I have several matrix jobs on a master-slave setup where slaves have only one executor. Sometimes when a matrix job executes, the main job (that triggers all the other ones) occupies a slave, but its subjobs can still run on that slave - which is what I want, since the main job really does not do anything. But sometimes the exact same job would occupy a slave and its subjobs block thinking that there are no available executors.

(1) Does anybody know why the behavior may be different? To me it looks like a bug, but possibly there are subtle reasons that I'm missing.

(2) Can you propose a workaround?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround: use [Matrix Tie Parent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Tie+Parent+Plugin) to tie the parent job to *master* (or some other node) that has multiple executors and is specifically dedicated for the purpose of running matrix parent jobs.